# Do sentient Artificial Intelligences have legal rights?

Tags: canada, us-constitution, human-rights

There has been lots of talk about whether sentient AI (assuming such emerge) would have rights under existing laws, but I don't understand it at all, from a legal standpoint.

Take the Declaration of Independence:

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created
> equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable
> Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of
> Happiness.

Or the Constitution, which uses the word 'people' throughout.

It makes it very clear that rights are given to humans - not to computers that might have a human thought process.

Or take the Canadian Bill of Rights:

> It is hereby recognized and declared that in Canada there have existed
> and shall continue to exist without discrimination by reason of race,
> national origin, colour, religion or sex, the following human rights
> and fundamental freedoms...

This also makes it abundantly clear that rights are extended to biological humans, not robo-Frankensteins.

Is there any logical arguement that AI should have rights, or is it all a foolish idea from a bunch of talking heads with no critical thinking skills?

Note: This is independent from the question of whether sentient AI *should* should have rights, the question is whether, under current legal systems, rights *would* extend to sentient AI.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is probably better suited to Philosophy SE.

Comment: Did you notice that the Canadian Bill of Rights does not actually say who has rights?

Comment: @user6726 it does if you keep reading - those rights are given to humans

Comment: @user6726 'race, national origin, colour, religion or sex' - robots maybe have colour, possibly national origin, but not the other things. Plus, it calls the human rights.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch How is this philosophy? I am asking if, under the current legal systems, the discussion about whether AI has rights carries legal weight. I would appreciate if you could reopen the question.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Whether AI should get rights philosophy-wise has nothing to do with the question of if rights would extend to AI.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this; it's asking "would a sentient AI have rights under current legal systems," not "should a sentient AI have rights under a perfect legal system."

Comment: @Someone Thanks.

Comment: @Someone I don't think there's a way to answer that without just giving an opinion..

Comment: @Michael How is that so? We can all agree that a sentient AI is not human - its a computer. So the question is, would legal rights be extended to a non-human but equally-sentient AI?

Comment: @KovyJacob but no courts have taken up that question, and there is no law addressing it, so any attempt to answer it that goes beyond "we don't know" would just be an opinion. There is some interesting case law about the personhood and rights non-human animals; a question about that might give you some insights into how the law would treat a hypothetical sentient AI.

Comment: For example, you talk about "sentient AI" but that term is meaningless in the eyes of the law. The law doesn't have a definition for sentient because we've never needed one.

Comment: @KovyJacob Did you know a corporation is a "person" within the meaning of the due process and equal protection clauses of the Fourteenth Amendment to the US Constitution? A number of jurisdictions have a concept called the "legal person". A legal person can be a human or a non-human entity ('juridical person'), for example a corporation, which can do (some) legal things that a human can do (e.g. own property, enter into contracts, sue other entities, be entitled to due process etc). Maybe a court will be persuaded that an AI entity is a 'legal person' and has such rights.

Comment: Note that the Declaration of Independence is not a source of law in the US. The basis for law in the US is the Constitution which was ratified 12 years later.  The Declaration of Independence was a public apologia for splitting from Great Britain. It provides insight into the philosophical viewpoints of the founders, but it's not the basis for any of our laws, and not comparable to the Canadian or US Bill of Rights.

Comment: @Lag That would be so interesting. Though they would always be property - I wonder if that would change anything.

Comment: @KovyJacob Also perhaps of interest, New Zealand has granted legal personhood to three geographical features: former national park Te Urewera, the Whanganui River and dormant volcano Mount Taranaki.

Comment: @Lag Wow that's crazy.

Answer (score 3):

### Because the courts or the legislature decide they have them

There is no doubt that both the courts and the legislature in common law countries have the ability to find, create, or extend rights and this has been done in the past.

This is, in fact, where legal rights were created. The US Bill of Rights was created by the people in 1791. If the people in 2191 want to grant rights to AIs then they can do this.

This is legally possible. Whether it's a good idea is a matter of philosophy and politics.

Comment: First of all, I am asking under the current law, not hypotheticals. Second of all, what is your basis for this? The constitution clearly states that the rights are for humans. You can make ammendments, but not change the outline.

Comment: @KovyJacob Constitutions change. The median age of the world’s constitutions is 7 years.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: @KobyJacob several amendments have made similar levels of changes: check the highlighted parts of https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/full-text

Comment: The Thirteenth Amendment overturned the Dred Scott v. Sandford ruling that slaves were not persons and recognized their rights as citizens (although black people did not have equal rights until much later); Dobbs allowed states to do the same with unborn children (but does not do so on its own or compel states to do so). There is definitely precedent for this.

Comment: @Someone the difference is that Black people are objectively people.

Comment: @KovyJacob unfortunately, that was not recognized as an objective truth at the time of _Dred Scott v. Sandford_ and the Thirteenth Amendment. Regarding whether the unborn are persons, that is still (as you are probably aware) a major topic of debate. There is precedent for entities who some people do not believe should be persons being given the legal rights of personhood.